# Markers Events Click Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

There is a Google Map on which points are uploaded as markers. It is necessary to make the route construction by points: Click on the point with the right mouse button and the point is added to the route.
I do not understand how to make the handler of mouse click events by the array of objects on the map. On the Yandex Maps it is done like this:

```
myMap.geoObjects.events.add ('contextmenu', function (e) {})
```

And what about Google maps? The idea should be something like this:

```
google.maps.Marker.addListener ('rightclick', function (e) {})
```

But this method does not work. How can I implement event handling?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbdxJ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your points are already in array. If so, all you need to do is just iterate to each point in your array and create a new instance of Google Marker and fill in the properties (*you can check **[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#introduction)** for Google Marker documentation)*. Then in each Marker, attach a listener that when 'rightclick' is clicked, it will add a new destination on your route. For more info about events, please check **[this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)** documentation.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initMap(){
        var sampleCoords = [ { lat:14.599512, lng:120.98422 },{ lat:14.554729, lng:121.024445 },{ lat:14.579444, lng:121.035917 } ];
        var options = { center : {  lat: 14.5995, lng:120.9842 }, zoom : 10, streetViewControl : false };
        var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options);
        for ( var key in sampleCoords ) {
            sampleCoords[key] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : new google.maps.LatLng( sampleCoords[key].lat,sampleCoords[key].lng ),
                map : map,
                title : 'test'
            });
            sampleCoords[key].addListener('rightclick', function(params){
                alert('Right clicked!')
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Working demo **[here](https://jsbin.com/wotepaxebo/edit?html,output)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add Route to Map Onclick</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html,body,#map {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzjs-bUR6iIl8yGLr60p6-zbdFtRpuXTQ&callback=initMap"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initMap(){
                var sampleCoords = [ { lat:14.599512, lng:120.98422 },{ lat:14.554729, lng:121.024445 },{ lat:14.579444, lng:121.035917 } ];
                var options = { center : {  lat: 14.5995, lng:120.9842 }, zoom : 10, streetViewControl : false };
                var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options);
                for ( var key in sampleCoords ) {
                    sampleCoords[key] = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position : new google.maps.LatLng( sampleCoords[key].lat,sampleCoords[key].lng ),
                        map : map,
                        title : 'test'
                    });
                    sampleCoords[key].addListener('rightclick', function(params){
                        alert('Right clicked!');
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If it helped, please consider accepting/upvoting my answer. Thanks :)